# c++ creating a static like array with "new" or another way of creating a dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, new-operator

I know that the common technique of creating a dynamic array using `new` in C++ is:

```
int * arr = new int[5];
```

A book also says:

```
short tell[10]; // tell is an array of 20 bytes
cout << tell << endl; // displays &tell[0]
cout << &tell << endl; // displays address of the whole array
short (*p)[10] = &tell; // p points to an array of 20 shorts
```

Now I wonder if there is a way to allocate memory for an array using `new`, so it can be then assigned to a pointer to the whole array. **It might look like this**:

```
int (*p)[5] = new int[5];
```

The above example doesn't work. The left side looks correct to me. But I don't know what should be on the right.

My intention is to understand if it's possible. And I know that there are `std::vector` and `std::array`.

**Update:**

Here is what I actually wanted to check:

```
int (*p1)[5] = (int (*)[5]) new int[5];
// size of the whole array
cout << "sizeof(*p1) = " << sizeof(*p1) << endl;

int * p2 = new int[5];
// size of the first element
cout << "sizeof(*p2) = " << sizeof(*p2) << endl;
```

And here is how to access these arrays:

```
memset(*p1, 0, sizeof(*p1));
cout << "p1[0] = " << (*p1)[0] << endl;

memset(p2, 0, sizeof(*p2) * 5);
cout << "p2[0] = " << p2[0] << endl;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> know that the common technique of creating a dynamic array

In C++ that was written 20 years ago, maybe.

These days you should use `std::vector` for dynamic arrays and `std::array` for fixed size array.

If your framework or platform supplies additional array classes (like QT's `QVector`), they are fine too, as long as you don't mess with C-pointers directly, and you have RAII-based array class.

and as for concrete answer, `new T[size]` always returns `T*` , so you cannot catch a pointer returned by `new[]` with `T(*)[size]`.

Comment: So, that means that it is not possible to allocate memory for this construction `int (*p)[5] =`. Right?

Comment: you can forcefully cast it with c-cast `(int(*)[5])new int[5]`, but please, don't do it in real code.

Comment: I am just playing around it and trying to get dipper understanding. BTW, why are you saying not to do it in real code?

Comment: because we don't use C pointers and C-casts unless we really have to. and I guess you don't really have to.

Comment: That is a good point =) . Many thanks. I've got what I want. Now I will supplement my question, because I cannot put a bloc of code here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that left and right sights have different types.

The type of:

```
new int[5]
```

is

```
int*.
```

The type of:

```
int (*p)[5]
```

is

```
int (*)[5].
```

And compiler cannot assign one to another.

Generally speaking it is impossible to assign `T*` to `T (*)[N]`. That is why you need to use the syntax mentioned in the beginning of your question.